# size efficient dictionary(associative array) implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

What algorithms are available for size efficient [A dictionary or associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)?
For example, with this key/value set, how can one avoid duplication "Alice" in values?

```
{
    "Pride and Prejudice": "Alice",
    "The Brothers Karamazov": "Pat",
    "Wuthering Heights": "Alice"
}
```

I checked [Python's implementation on dictionary](http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/), but it seems like the implementation is focused on speed (keeping O(1)) not size.

Comment: Keep a second dictionary mapping value ids (e.g. hashes) to values, use value ids in this one.

Comment: Should your data structure support mutable *values*?

Comment: I think you could store the result of sys.intern if you only want strings as values.

Comment: @Pavel: It wouldn't be quite that simple because there could be hash value id collisions.

Comment: Swap your key and values?

Comment: Would a graph be a better datatype?  Multiple values can belong to `Alice` but there would only be one `Alice`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [bennofs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2494803/bennofs) in comments, you could use [`intern()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) to ensure that identical strings are stored only once:

```
class InternDict(dict):

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            super(InternDict, self).__setitem__(key, intern(value))
        else:
            super(InternDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

Here's an example of the effect that has:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d["a"] = "This string is presumably too long to be auto-interned."
>>> d["b"] = "This string is presumably too long to be auto-interned."
>>> d["a"] is d["b"]
False
>>> di = InternDict()
>>> di["a"] = "This string is presumably too long to be auto-interned."
>>> di["b"] = "This string is presumably too long to be auto-interned."
>>> di["a"] is di["b"]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to improve space efficiency (in addition to sharing values, which (as bennofs points out in the comments) you can probably accomplish efficiently by using sys.intern) is to use [hopscotch hashing](http://mcg.cs.tau.ac.il/projects/hopscotch-hashing-1), which is an open addressing scheme (a variant of linear probing) for resolving collisions - closed addressing schemes use more space because you need to allocate a linked list for each bucket, whereas with an open addressing scheme you'll just use an open adjacent slot in the backing array without needing to allocate any linked lists.  Unlike other open addressing schemes (such as cuckoo hashing or vanilla linear probing), hopscotch hashing performs well under a high load factor (over 90%) and guarantees constant time lookups.

Answer (score 0):

- **If your dictionary can fit in memory then, a simple Hashtable can be use.**

Try to insert every key-value in an hashtable.
If the key alredy exist before inserting, then you have found a duplication.
There is number of implementation of [hashtable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) in many langage.

There is basically twice way : array & tree.

- [Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) focus on speed at hight memory cost. The main difference between Hashtable implementation is behavior on unicity, some implementation enforce unicity some others no.
- Tree focus on memory smart usage at cost of O(log(n)) cpu usage. g++ map relies on very power full [red black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_black_tree).

If size is very very problematics, then you should search a [Huffman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) compression and/or [Lampel Ziv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ77_and_LZ78) compression, but it cost a little more, to adapt for dictionnary.

- **If your dictionnary can't fit in memory**

You should look at database.
The *red black tree* for database is know as [BTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btree)  (almost). It have branch factor optimizations for the low latency hard drive case.

I have put many link to wikipedia but if you like this subject I recommand you :

[image: Introduction to algorithms]